# One axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to make one axis exercices for students, thus I try to customize pgflots but I don't understand what append in this examples :

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest, %footnotesize
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend style={font=\small},
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    every axis/.style={pin distance=1ex}
    %xlabel near ticks
%   
    }   %%%% fin pgfplotsset


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-3,xmax=3,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,ymin=0,ymax=1,
xmin=-3,xmax=3,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-3,xmax=3,
xticklabels={8,3,,5,,7},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-3,xmax=3,
xticklabels={8,3,,5,,7},
extra x ticks={.75},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the first : xmin, xmax doesn't work ?
In the second : with it works in the second ?
In the third : where is the first 8 ?
In the forth : where is extra tick ?

Once the initial 8 from xlabels appears on the place of extra label !
I use texlive with both last versions of pgf-tikz and pgfplots.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you check your `.log` file, you will see `Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 34.` So because you didn't specify a range for the y direction (and you didn't give PGFPlots a chance to figure it out itself by providing a plot, for example), PGFPlots reverts to the default axis limits. Simply adding `ymin=0, ymax=1`, for instance, will solve this problem (which is what you did in the second axis). This should be done for all your axes.
2. See 1.
3. `xticklabels` when used with automatically determined tick positions sometimes swallows the first tick label. The safest bet is to set `xtick={-3,...,3}` to explicitly specify that there should be tick marks at every integer position between `-3` and `3`.
4. See 1. Note that in this case you should also provide a list of labels for the extra tick positions, otherwise PGFPlots will use the same list as for the main ticks and label the first extra tick with `8`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest, %footnotesize
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend style={font=\small},
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    every axis/.style={pin distance=1ex},
    trim axis left
    %xlabel near ticks
%   
    }   %%%% fin pgfplotsset


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-3,xmax=3,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,ymin=0,ymax=1,
xmin=-3,xmax=3,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=0, ymax=1,
xtick={-3,...,3},
xticklabels={8,3,,5,,7},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-3,xmax=3, ymin=0, ymax=1,
xtick={-3,...,3},
xticklabels={8,3,,5,,7},
extra x ticks={.75},
extra x tick labels={x}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```